# Android soft keyboard edit field

Tags: java, android, kotlin

When I click a floating button in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRxh8.png), the soft keyboard will show with edit field like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDpRM.png). I don't know the keyword to search the edit field of soft keyboard. Thanks for reading !

Answer (score 0):

Use `Editext` and add a field to your `editext` `android:hint`. see the code below :

```
 <EditText
       android:id="@+id/toDo" 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:hint="Add a To Do"/>
```

Comment: Hi Vikas, I have update my question for clearly. I want to know name of edit field in soft keyboard. Anyway, thanks for your answer :) !

Comment: Ok, Just explain little bit more what you want. May be I can help you